# Running Unique PowerQueries Based on a Cell Value

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I have a pretty simple query in excel that takes a few set areas of data and combines them, then groups that data together. The merged queries look something like this:

```
Description     Rate      Quantity             
Type 1           2          .1                
Type 1           2          .1
Type 1           3          .1
Type 2           3          .1
Type 2           3          .1
```

When they group that data together, it will look like this:

```
Description     Rate     Quantity             
Type 1           2          .2         
Type 1           3          .1
Type 2           3          .2
```

All it is doing is grouping together the different kind of descriptions and rates, so with the two "Type 1" at a rate of 2, that makes for a quantity of .2, and so on.

However, there is another method to rolling these together. This would be like so:

```
Description     Rate     Quantity             
Type 1           2          .3         
Type 2           3          .2
```

What this is doing is rolling up based on the description, but using the first rate that appears, instead of charging two different rates. So three "Type 1"s when the first rate that appears is 2, will always be at that 2 rate, even if another rate appears later.

**The actual method of making the queries do this is simple and something I have done. Where I am struggling, however, is wondering if it is possible to tell PowerQuery to use that first grouping method when a particular cell in that workbook equals "1", and that second grouping method when that cell equals "2".**

Right now I have it set to simply output both types and let the user select which type is necessary, but it would be great to eliminate as many decisions as possible for the user.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make that cell into a named range.
2. [Reference that named range with Power Query](https://www.howtoexcel.org/power-query/how-to-reference-a-named-range-in-power-query/)
3. Write a new query that switches which query to output based on the named range.

```
let
    NamedRange = GetNamedRangeQuery
    Output = if NamedRange = 1 then Query1 else Query2
in
    Output
```